# Density of $\cos(\ln(n))$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, trigonometry

I tried so much in solving but I reached nothing.

Question: Show that $C= \{ \cos(\ln(n)) \colon n \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$ is dense in $[-1,+1].$

Please help in solving it :)

Comment: and I didn't know how to solve it...

Comment: Do you know/are able to prove that $\{e^{in}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is dense in the unit circle? Do you realize $\log n$ grows so slowly that it ensures $\{n^i\}_{n\geq 1}$ to be dense in the unit circle? Do you realize that $z\to\text{Re}(z)$ is a continuous map, hence it preserves density?

Comment: Sorry but what you said is not included in the course  I learn...

Comment: Then you should be more specific about what we are allowed to use and what not, since we are not your classmates. Additionally, my previous request was for your actual attempts, that you do not really mention. So I renew the request: *so much* means what, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Interesting property of the sequence $(\ln n)$: $\ln n \to \infty,$ even though $\ln (n+1) - \ln n \to 0.$ So when $N$ is large, the numbers $\ln n$ that lie in the interval $[2\pi N,2\pi N+2\pi ]$ will subdivide that interval into very small pieces.